# Thesis formatting problem in Latex/ Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, thesis

I am using the Overleaf thesis format and I would like to change some parts of the thesis because the style is a little bit different. I am using the below style

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/thesis-template-for-university-at-buffalo/gvttxscsrwzm

Firstly, I tried a lot to delete the rectangle box make some font size for both **Chapter 1** but I unable to remove it. Require Some help please.

[image]

Secondly, I would like to change the font family of the above thesis and try to use the font family of the below thesis. I do not know the font family name of the below thesis.

http://cvpr.sejong.ac.kr/assets/pdf/hmoon_thesis.pdf

Lastly, I would like to change the font color of the list of contents from Blue to Black, I failed.

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted the Overleaf Help Desk? I hear their LaTeX support staff are top-notch.

Comment: The PDF file of Hyeonjoon Moon's Thesis contains the following fonts: Bookman, AvantGarde, Helvetica, Times Roman and Courier.

Comment: @Mico Sorry I didn't contact overleaf. If you help please, I will be very thankful to you. please

Comment: @KhawarIslam - Given that you appear to be relying heavily on a document provided by Overleaf, I really do think that you should work with their support staff first.

Comment: Thank you. I will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)** Remove from the preamble this two lines

```
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\ChTitleVar{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
```

to get the LaTex style chapter titles.

[image: B]

**(2)** Change

`\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=purple,citecolor=green,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}` to

`\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=purple,citecolor=green,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}`

for a black font color of the table of contents.

[image: a]

**(3)** Fonts used by the linked thesis. Although Acrobat will list several fonts, the important ones are Bookman for text and tables (normalsize 11pt), AvantGarde for page headings and Swiss 721 SWA inside the  figures.